# Git: Removing a folder with \r in the path

Tags: git

So somehow OS X allowed me to create a folder with the name "assets\rassets\rassets". Yep, those are \r linebreaks.

Now I've renamed it, but git can't find it to remove it.

```
git rm "assets\rassets\rassets/default_app_icon.psd"
fatal: pathspec 'assets\rassets\rassets/default_app_icon.psd' did not match any files
```

All combinations of escaping with \ and " don't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because '\r' doesn't really mean anything to git or your shell. You need to give it an *actual* carriage return character.

You can use bash's filename completion to accomplish this -- just type 'git rm assets', and start hitting tab until you get where you need to be.

You can also use the shell command `printf` with backticks. This should work (just did for me on OS X):

```
git rm `printf 'assets\rassets\rassets/default_app_icon.psd'`
```

The `printf` command works like C's `printf()`, with support for all the same escape characters (including '\r').